# leaflet - manually cluster markers

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I need to manually cluster/uncluster few markers on the map (not automatically by zoom)

is there a way to tell Leaflet.markercluster which markers to cluster manually and not automatically by zoom.

I tried manipulating the L.markerClusterGroup layer internal `cluster._gridClusters` and `cluster._gridUnclustered` which holds an array of all the zooms and markers/clusters in each. 
but changing the objects seems to do nothing and not represented on map.

a solution example would be:

```
selectedMarkers = [marker1,marker2,marker3];
map.cluster(selectedMarkers);
map.uncluster(selectedMarkers);
```

please help.

Comment: Adding some sketches of what you are trying to achieve would greatly help.

Comment: just cluster a few markers manually.

Comment: not clear please elaborate.

Comment: disable the zoom clustering and telling marker.cluster to group certain markers manually.